# From Java to Kinect programming

Tags: kinect

I have no experience in C# or .NET programming, but interested in developing with Kinect. Are there any good Java libs, open source projects for such stuff? Or C# + .NET is the only way?

Comment: Here is a link to get you started: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page It has libraries for many languages including Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long it takes to adapt a new language is only up to you and your background.

However there is a very decent project called [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) that has a Java (JNI and JNA) Wrappers.

you can lookup [CLNUI4J](http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2010/11/19/clnui-4-java-kinect/) for another reference for a Java framework for Kinect